# Problem with UV and texture

Tags: texturing, uv

When I unwrapped my mesh and then fill some faces by default fill tool, I got next:

[image: artifacts]

When I saw in my UV I have understood, that problem is in next parts of UV, which were not filled (why?):

[image: problem uv]

What should I do to fix it?

Sorry for my english. Thank you in advance

Comment: you can paint the holes with the TexDraw brush even with no texture selected. Просто кисточкой замазать :-)

Comment: and what does this whiteness mean on your texture? if there is another UV island there filled white, then it could be some color bleeding because the UV regions are too close to each other. If it's the case, make the gaps wider. Also there is the "Bleed" parameter on the Options tab of the tool-shelf in the texture paint mode.